# Same models appearing in conflicting models error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I shifted my project apps to a folder named 'modules' and now when I try to run the project. I get an error

```
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'someappuser' models in application 
'authentication': <class 'users.models.someAppUser'> and <class 
'modules.users.models.someAppUser'>.
```

It is basically the same model but the system is treating them as different directories, and hence different models

Project Hierarchy:

```
SomeApp
- settings.py
- manage.py
- __init__.py
- urls.py
- views.py
- modules
 +users
 +models.py
 +views.py
 +urls.py
```

Settings.py-

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
BASE_DIR = 
os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'modules'))
```

Comment: Correction: In the modules folder, I have app 'User' that further expands to init.py, models, views and urls

Comment: What do you have for `INSTALLED_APPS` and do you have `someAppUser` as a model defined in both SomeApp/users/models.py and SomeApp/modules/users/models.py?

Comment: Model is only defined in SomeApp/modules/users/models.py.

        
`INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'SomeApp',
    'users',
    'authentication',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social_django',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_extensions',
]`

@schillingt

Comment: I don't think `SomeApp` should be in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. All I needed to correct was changing my 'appname' in INSTALLED_APPS to 'AppFolderName.appname'